# Error: Failed to execute goal on project xxxx inside jenkins build

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

when i run the build in jenkins i got below error when i am trying to run in local its building fine.

```
  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project xxx: Could not resolve dependencies for project xxx:xxx-bin:pom:10-2.1.0-test: The following artifacts could not be resolved: xxx-alerts:alerts-loader:jar:xxx:3-95210ce313-2.1.0-test, xxx-alerts:alerts-loader:zip:resources:3-95210ce313-2.1.0-test: Failure to find xxx-alerts:alerts-loader:jar:deps:3-95210ce313-2.1.0-test in http://xxx:8080/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete ~.m2\repository and this should work for you.
Also, make sure u run the mvn command with clean before install